# Polymer and globals

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm getting into Polymer and i like the deps resolution approach using imports.
And i like the extending capability through the `behaviors` config.
However, there's something that doesn't feel comfortable to me, about behaviors in particular.
Looking at the [PolymerElements](https://github.com/PolymerElements) code i see that behaviors, are defined inside their own html in the global object `Polymer` and then referenced directly when imported by another component..
For example:

`paper-button` imports `paper-button-behavior`
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button.html#L14

it then defines `paper-button-behavior` as behavior referencing from global `Polymer.PaperButtonBehavior`
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button.html#L144

wich is defined here (the imported html)
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-behaviors/blob/master/paper-button-behavior.html#L49

Ain't it an anti-pattern, especially as typically an app will not use Polymer's world exclusively?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning.  This practice does not seem to preclude the use of any other libraries or frameworks in any way, and the behaviors seem to be namespaced decently enough that collisions would be exceedingly rare.

Comment: @Zikes I see.. Just, I always avoided using globals for my modules, resolving deps by mean of some AMD loader, with exception of some *public* library that do not support AMD. And that was the *trend* last years, and the globals were kind of anti-pattern or *public-lib-only*, so i was just wondering if this trend is kinda overturn when resolving deps with *link import*

Comment: I published a related topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618325/mocking-polymer-imports)