# Mocking Polymer imports

Tags: unit-testing, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Is there a reliable way to mock imported dependencies in Polymer (or vanilla web components)?
I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092109/polymer-unit-test-mocking-dependencies) and other resources where they suggest to previously define the mocked custom element.
While this approach will actually mock the custom-element definition, it will not prevent the original dep to be imported later **and its scripts executed !**
This would surely lead to conflicts, inconsistences, and unwanted code execution where the dependencies do not *just merely* define an element.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597614/polymer-and-globals) as a related topic